# Flutter shorebird abort every command

Tags: flutter, shorebird

I use shorebird for code push and not use for that project for around 3 month.And I need that again to do code push my project and I use again, but shorebird aborting every command, even `shorebird --help` for now. How it can be? How can I fix? I search that error on everywhere but not found.

[image]